# Decorate Javascript Promise.then so that the argument function receive additional parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have the following code using ES6 Promise :

```
const ctx = {}
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => doSomethingWith(ctx))
  .then((retValue) => doSomethingElseWith(retValue, ctx))
```

I would like to be able to do something like this :

```
const ctx = {}
using(ctx)
   .then((ctx) => doSomethingWith(ctx))
   .then((retValue, ctx) => doSomethingElseWith(retValue, ctx))
```

For the first `then`, I have something like this :

```
function using(ctx) {
  const p = Promise.resolve()
  p.then = (fn) => withCtx(fn, ctx)
  return p
}

function withCtx (fn, ctx) {
  const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(fn.apply(this, [ctx]))
  })
  return p
}
```

But I would like it to handle the case of the second then that takes both the previous promise returned value and the context... How could I have this part :

```
fn.apply(this, [ctx]) // want previous promise returned value and ctx here !
```

handle the case fn already takes a parameter we want to propagate... the `retValue` case describe above.

Any idea ? (the use case I want to cover after is to be able to stop the Promise chain at any time, persist values on disk and restart at any time with altered context restored from disk)

Comment: Is `ctx` literally in the same scope as the callback functions? Or is it more like `return using(ctx);` and the `then` callbacks will be attached elsewhere…?

Comment: `ctx` must not be considered as always in the scope... I want to be able to wrap around functions passed to `then` so I can process/alter `retValue` & `ctx` in an AOP fashion

Comment: you could always write your own Promise implementation - as you can't change the "native" one to do your bidding

Comment: *"you could always write your own Promise implementation"* - I don't think that's a sensible thing to recommend. Writing a promise implementation is not exactly trivial - and it has already been done. Simply use an existing one.

Comment: You can look into bound promises, as bluebird offers them: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.bind.html. Maybe rewriting your functions so that they do not depend on outer-scope state would be an option, too?

Comment: What exactly do you need this `ctx` for? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to me

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I think it's confusing and probably an anti pattern, but can you pass mutable state between promises simply by adding an extra `then`

```
Promise.resolve({}) 
.then(ctx => doSomethingWith(ctx)
  .then(ret => ({ret, ctx})))
.then(({ret, ctx}) => doSomethingElseWith(ret, ctx))
```

The second `then` is inside the first one and therefore has a closure on the input state, which it can decorate with the transformed value, before passing the mutated context to the next phase. This achieved without leaking any references to the global context.

To show what it looks like if you extend the pattern...

```
function trans (that, y) {
  console.dir(y);
  return new Promise(res =>
    setTimeout(res.bind(null, that.op(y)), 1000)
  )
}

Promise.resolve({ret: 0, ctx: {op: _ => _ + 2}})
  .then(({ret, ctx}) => trans(ctx, ret)
    .then(ret =>({ ret, ctx}))
  )
  .then(({ret, ctx}) => trans(ctx, ret)
    .then(ret =>({ ret, ctx}))
  )
  .then(({ret, ctx}) => trans(ctx, ret)
    .then(ret =>({ ret, ctx}))
  )
  .then(({ret, ctx}) => trans(ctx, ret)
    .then(ret =>({ ret, ctx}))
  )
  .then(ctx => console.dir(ctx));
  .catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

Comment: This is not an antipattern. And you don't even need to actually mutate the `ctx`, you can also pass on a new (cloned) one

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for the edit.  I haven't been using destructuring assignments in function arguments because it throws in node (5.12).  Inspired by your edit, I tested it in Chrome v53 and it does indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

The following may be the pattern you are looking for:

```
something0()
  .then(result0 => something1(ctx, result0)
    .then(result1 => something2(ctx, result0, result1)
      .then(result2 => something3(ctx, result0, result1, result2))
    )
  )
;
```

Yes, it is a sort of pyramid of doom, but there's no other way to keep the previous results in scope for use later down the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Worth keeping in mind that if you need to pass more than one value through a computation, then you can simply return a list (Array) of multiple values/results from your .then functions:

```
Promise.resolve(6)
  .then( x => [x+6, x] )
  .then( ([latestVal, oldvalue]) => /*whatever*/ );
```

There's nothing wrong with this approach and there are various other methods (like `unapply/apply` you can use to modify your handler functions in order to receive/work with Arrays as return types (which you should really think of as *nested* types: you're now working over a Promise[Array[...values]] which is actually pretty common pattern.

Note that this works even if some of the values are themselves derived from async operations: just pass them into Promise.all and it will turn an Array of values/Promises into a Promise of an Array, and you can then just destructure the Array to get at your various results.

```
Promise.resolve(6)
  .then( x => Promise.all([additionApi(x), x]) )
  .then( ([latestVal, ...rest]) => Promise.all( additionApi(x).concat(latest, rest) ) )
  .then( ([latestVal, ...rest]) => Promise.all( additionApi(x).concat(latest, rest) ) );
  //...etc.
```